# Reducing Pocket app size

Tags: ios, applications

I have the Pocket app on an iPhone and an iPad. When I check storage usage, they are over 2 and 4 GBs, respectively. Why is the size so big in both cases? The app itself is under 100 MBs according to the App Store. All the saved articles are just text. I have no videos or images.

More importantly, is there a way to reduce the space taken up by the app? There does not seem to be a way to delete archived articles.

Comment: I saw [this article](http://stuarte.co/2014/delete-pocket-app-storage/) from someone with the same question earlier in the year.  They were told to log out from Pocket and then log back in.  Try that, and restart your device to be sure, and see if that helps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pocket's customer support gave [this information](http://stuarte.co/2014/delete-pocket-app-storage/) to another user who had a very similar problem (albeit in 2014):

> [When an item has] been Archived or Deleted ... we attempt to remove all associated files. However, we have learned more recently that some information can be retained under certain circumstances. This is why logging out and back in dropped Pocket’s storage usage so dramatically.

Logging out and back in causes the entire local storage to be cleared, at which point only items on your List (not Archived) are re-downloaded.

They also said they were adding a way to limit storage usage as well as make cache cleanup more efficient, though that does not seem to be true in your case.

Comment: that link looks familiar... :-)

Comment: @fbara I don't know what you're talking about ;)

Comment: Logging out did not clear the cache. I even tried restarting the device. However, logging out and deleting the app cleared the cache. Installing the app again kept it at a reasonable size even after a few days of use.

Comment: The next step would be to delete the app, do a hard reset and then reinstall.